# Apply a split based on a certain condition

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, split

I've the following dataframe:

```
data = {'Name': ['Peter | Jacker', 'John | Parcker', 'Paul | Cash', 'Tony'],
        'Age': [10, 45, 14, 65]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

What I want to extract is the nicknames (the word after the character '|') only for the person that have more than 16 years. For that I am using the following code:

```
df['nickname'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.split('|', 1)[-1] if x['Age'] > 16 else 0, axis=1)
```

However, when I print the nickname I only getting the following results:

```
     Name      Age  nickname
Peter | Jacker  10   0.0     
John | Parcker  45  NaN      
Paul | Cash     14   0.0     
Tony            65  NaN
```

And what I want is this:

```
     Name      Age  nickname
Peter | Jacker  10   NaN    
John | Parcker  45   Parcker      
Paul | Cash     14   NaN     
Tony            65   NaN
```

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with select second lists after `split` if condition match, else add mising values (or `0`, what need):

```
df['nickname'] = np.where(df['Age'] > 16, df['Name'].str.split('|', 1).str[1] , np.nan)
print (df)
             Name  Age  nickname
0  Peter | Jacker   10       NaN
1  John | Parcker   45   Parcker
2     Paul | Cash   14       NaN
3            Tony   65       NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply split function on name column. Try below code:

`import numpy as np`

`df.apply(lambda x: x['Name'].split('|', 1)[-1] if x['Age'] > 16 and len(x['Name'].split('|',1))>1 else np.nan, axis=1)`

```
             Name  Age  nickname
0  Peter | Jacker   10       NaN
1  John | Parcker   45   Parcker
2     Paul | Cash   14       NaN
3            Tony   65       NaN
```